# Merge strings and table to one text file using fprintf - Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, printf

How can I save the information generate in the script below which include strings and table in the following format to a text file?

Format:

```
M=5
1 21
2 22
3 23
4 24
5 25
5points
```

Script:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

ElmentsNum = "EM=5";
x = (1:5)';
y =(21:25)';
t = table(x,y);
M = "5points"
  
fileID = fopen('E:/Data.txt');
fprintf(fileID,'%s/n',ElmentsNum)
fprintf(fileID,'%.4f',t)
fprintf(fileID,'%s/n',M)
fclose(fileID)
```

Comment: `clear all` is very seldomly necessary. `clear` by itself clears all variables from the workspace, and is what you are attempting to do. `clear all` also unloads all previously loaded function definitions, meaning that they will all be loaded again when you use them, slowing down your code.

Answer (score 5):

Quite simple, just extract the values of the table, then write them line by line:

```
extracted_table=table2array(t);

fileID = fopen('Data.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n',ElmentsNum);
for ii=1:size(extracted_table,1)
%     fprintf(fileID,'%.4f %.4f\n',extracted_table(ii,:)); % if you want decimal places
    fprintf(fileID,'%d %d\n',extracted_table(ii,:)); % if you want integers (as in the example)
end
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n',M);
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: `%g` would give you *"The more compact of `%e` or `%f`, with no trailing zeros"* (from the docs) so that eases the `%d`/`%.4f` decision making :)

Comment: @Wolfie Good point! As often the code that reads the files may need X amount of floating point precision, I will leave my answer as is, but OP should definitely note your comment